# Building an image via Dockerfile (creating a folder in /dev)

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, docker-image

I am trying to build an image and following error occurs:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /dev/lab3/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/dev/lab3/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Here we have Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /dev/lab3
COPY server.js .
COPY package.json .
RUN mkdir /files
ADD ./files /files
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Look at df -h:

```
root@279f05c372ce:/dev# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay         118G   13G   99G  11% /
tmpfs            64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda5       118G   13G   99G  11% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/firmware
```

My assumption - while building an image, WORKDIR sets /dev/lab3 for working directory. /dev is tmpfs filesystem (temporary), so when next layers of image are created (COPY server.js and COPY package.json) there is no /lab3 folder.
Could you confirm this ? Or there is other explaination?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! `/dev` is not a common place for application files. Can you try using `/opt/` or `/src/` instead?

Comment: Yes, I can of course. But I wish to obtain an explaination about /dev or generally tmpfs :)

Comment: `/dev` is a special directory for linux device "files". https://tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/dev-fs.html

Answer (score 2):

The `/dev` folder is for devices (like hard drives and ttys) in Linux. User applications do no belong there. Docker manages this directory because some special devices are expected in Linux (e.g. `/dev/zero` and `/dev/random`) so it configures an in memory filesystem (tmpfs) and mounts that in the container filesystem namespace. When you mount a directory in Linux, files and directories in the underlying filesystem are hidden for as long as that mount exists (in this case, for the lifetime of the container).